# int and unsigned int in c

Tags: c

```
main()
{
    int x=12;
    unsigned int y=12;

    if (x>y)
    {
        printf("abc");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("xyz");
    }
}
```

What is the output ?

Comment: Why don't you compile the code and check?

Comment: Compile it and run it and see!  Or work it out, do you think 12 > 12 or that the signed or unsigned type of the same integer value makes any difference (other than the compiler warnings it will yield)?

Comment: Compile it and see. If you don't *understand* why the output is what it is, ask that instead!

Answer (score 4):

After fixing the compiler errors, the signed `int` is converted to unsigned, due to the rules on Usual arithmetic conversions (C99 §6.3.1.8):

> Otherwise, if the operand that has
>   unsigned integer type has rank greater
>   or equal to the rank of the type of
>   the other operand, then the operand
>   with signed integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with
>   unsigned integer type.

It behaves as expected here, because 12 is within the range of `unsigned int`.

However, if you use `x = -2;` as suggested  in your comment, it will be converted to `-2 + UINT_MAX` (per §6.3.1.3, Signed and unsigned integers).

`-2 + UINT_MAX > 12` is true, so `abc` will print.

Answer (score 3):

That code does not compile. For what it's worth, my compiler gives the following output:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:1: error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
foo.cpp:1: error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
foo.cpp:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

After fixing the errors, the program outputs `xyz`, which is expected because `signed 12` is not greater than `unsigned 12`.

Comment: thank you so much............what happen if i write int x=-2 at place of int x=12

Comment: That's because you're using a C++ compiler, but the question is tagged C, so you should use a C compiler.

Comment: @dreamlax, actually, at the time I answered the question was tagged `output` :)

Comment: @Frédéric: Fair enough :) but the question was still titled "int and unsigned int in C"

Comment: @ranjeet, if I do that, the compiler expectedly complains with `warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions`, so I can't trust the program's output anymore.

Comment: @dreamlax, you're right, I probably missed the title :)

Comment: @Frédéric, that warning is because people can be surprised by the behavior.  However, it's still well-defined, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Matthew, absolutely, but it's arguably better to avoid that situation, even if it's well-defined. I'd listen to the warning :)

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: This answer is C99 specific.

Return type of `main` is missing (should be int), so your code should not compile.

Furthermore

```
int main()
{
    int x=12;
    unsigned int y=12;

    if (x>y)
    {
        printf("abc");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("xyz");
    }
}
```

invokes UB because `<stdio.h>` is missing

> J.2 **Undefined behavior**
>
> — For call to a function without a function prototype in scope where the function is defined with a function prototype, either the prototype ends with an ellipsis or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters (6.5.2.2).

Comment: Is it really UB or is it just a compile error?

Comment: Oh, you were referring to main, not printf.

Comment: @Falmarri : Its UB. UB means anything can happen and that includes compiler error too.

Comment: Where is the unattributed standards quote from!? An unadorned main() is entirely valid ISO C90 code, even if it is just bad practise.  It is also valid in C90 to omit function prototypes; it is also of course bad practise.

Comment: Furthermore in C90 if you explicitly declare main() to return an int, then it must have a return statement too (unlike C++)

Comment: Then you should state that in the answer.  All your comments are predicated on the use of C99, but it is entirely legitimate for questioner to be using a C89/90 compiler.  In fact given the prevalence of ancient compilers used in academia, highly likely.  I don't think you are wrong, but the answer is likely to confuse without qualification.  That said he hardly deserved a straight answer for such blatant laziness.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included library files, return type of main is not necessary unless you set compiler to strict behavior. so making another assumption that you have not set compiler to behave strictly!, end result would be

xyz

as @Matthew Flaschen said, after conversion, both will be same so first condition wont met and it would go in else part.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* get a compiler warning saying signed/unsigned mismatch, but it may get optimized away if the compiler determines the values are constant.